# Finding form fields in a Rails POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http-headers, http-post, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm using a plain old HTML form to send a post request to a rails app. Inside the app I would like to grab some of the input fields. I'm having trouble finding them inside the request.

Trying this:

```
logger.debug "Request Headers #{request.headers.inspect}"
```

Spits out a massive amount of data but I cannot find my form fields in there. Does anyone know where I can find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the request parameters submitted using:

```
logger.debug params.inspect
```

That will show all the form data submitted.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, when I do that I get `Request Headers {"controller"=>"users", "action"=>"handle_info"}` which is my object and my controller. But still no form fields.

Comment: Never mind, found here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html that appending a name attribute in html lets these fields show up.